# How do I see Tasks in an Area

Tags: azure-devops

I have inherited a Visual Studio Team Services instance and it has a single project that covers all development in a certain area (BizTalk).
However, we run more than one Biztalk development project and so we require Epics, Stories and Tasks to be split into Areas, otherwise all tasks for different developments show up in the same Backlog list.
However, when I create an Area as a sub of the top level and set the work items to use that date I can no longer see that work item in the Backlog.
I thought I could select the Area from the Project drop-down but it is not there. 
I can still see the Work Items if I use a query.

How do I set up VSTS so that I can see sub Areas in the Backlog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign Areas and Iterations to the Team. Then all the work items in those areas *and* in those iterations will show up in the Backlog of the Team.

Example:

To select areas for team 'Team UI 1' in team project 'alm_vsts', assure you have on the top right:
[image: alm_vsts/Team UI 1 context menu selected]

Then select the settings (i.e. the gear icon   [image: settings icon]), then select `Work`. You will see beneath the 'Iterations' and 'Areas' tabs.

Select 'Areas' and you could see the areas selected (or assigned to) the team 'Team UI 1':

[image: areas assigned to a team]

For each area you could decide whether to include sub areas or not (as shown in screenshot).

The same stands for the Iterations.

Hence you must select the Areas and the Iterations that the work item must have in order to appear on the Backlog for your team.

*Note*: if you need more then one hierarchical backlog (containing on multiple levels user stories, features, epics), you must create one team each hierarchical backlog.

Comment: There's a bit more to do afterwards to make it work:  
From the Project menu (top left) select the Project/Area. 
You get this error "TF400509: No backlog iteration path was specified..."
Click "Set backlog iteration".  
Set Default and Backlog Iteration to Project/Iteration
Click Area
Set the Default Area to Project/Area
Click Select Area(s)
Tick Include sub areas
Select your Project/Area
Now you can open a Work Item and set the Area and Iteration to your new Area and Iteration.
The new sub Area is selectable from the Project menu and the Work Items are visible.

Answer (score -1):

Using [Teams](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/scale/culture) may solve your problem. When you create a Team, you have automatically an Area and work items are filtered on that Area in Backlog and Boards.

Comment: Adding teams just leads to more problems as I then cannot create itterations.  I'd rather just know how to see Areas